# HTML Canvas - Adjust opacity of multiple elements as a layer

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to find a way to draw multiple elements onto an HTML canvas, then adjust all of their opacities at once. For example, [this codepen example](https://codepen.io/ryanoddstageten/pen/zYWEbGO?editors=0011) draws two overlapping rectangles with `globalAlpha` set to `0.5`, so they're semi-transparent.

Here's what I see:

[image]

Here's what I want to see:

[image]

In other words, I want to draw some set of elements, then adjust their alpha/opacity all at once. In the example above, I want the overlapping section of blue & red to appear as just blue, since the blue rectangle was drawn 2nd.

I want this solution to apply to images, shapes, any canvas drawings really.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this using HTML canvas?

Answer (score 0):

you must decompose the process
1- create de canvas with all draw ( alpha 100%)
2 set aside the flattened drawings
3 clear the canvas
4 fetch the picture and add it to the canvas
5 set alpha to 50%
6 add the tmp flattened drawings with alpha

```js
const cnv = document.createElement("canvas");
cnv.width = 300;
cnv.height = 300;
const ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");

document.body.appendChild(cnv);


// Draw red rectangle
ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, cnv.width - 140, cnv.height - 60);

// Draw blue rectangle
ctx.fillStyle = "#00f";
ctx.fillRect(100, 40, cnv.width - 140, cnv.height - 60);



//aside the draw in flatten layer
let tmp = new Image();
tmp.src = cnv.toDataURL();

// clear the canvas 
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height);

// apply bg
ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height);

const image = new Image(); // Using optional size for image
image.src = "https://img.photographyblog.com/reviews/kodak_pixpro_fz201/photos/kodak_pixpro_fz201_01.jpg";
image.onload = () => {
  // Draw background image
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.width);

  // Set alpha to 0.5
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
  
  //overlay with the tmp flatten img with 50%
  ctx.drawImage(tmp, 0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.width);

}
```

Comment: A canvas is already a CanvasImageSource, so you don't need step 2 and 4, draw directly the canvas / use a detached canvas.

Comment: step 2 is for me the way to combine all draws  in flat  'png' like (with alpha), how do you do this  with another canvas ? ovelapping? 
step 4 is to get  the background picture (from a cdn or a other domain) 
then i put the flatten draws over the bg
I'm curious to see your way of doing @Kaiido

Comment: Don't export your canvas to an HTMLImageElement (`tmp`). Make `tmp` a  canvas directly and draw on it: https://jsfiddle.net/r5sbyxan/ (And I may have misread what step4 was, I thought it was fetching `tmp`, which might be actually part of step 6).